# Enable Hardware Virtualization on HP CompaqDX2420?

Tags: vmware-workstation

After installing vmware7, I tried to run a virtual machine with Mac OSX installed. When I tried to run this virtual machine I got an error message saying: 
**Mac OS X is not supported with software virtualization. To run Mac OS X you need a host on which VMware Workstation supports hardware virtualization.**
I'v googled and found out that my processor [(Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 Processor (2.93 GHz, 3 MB L2 cache, 1066 Mhz FSB)](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=36503)supports Hardware virtualization. Does anyone know how to enable this in order to get this virtual machine running?

Comment: I have the same problem although I enabled the Bios !

Comment: Which Mac Os version are you using ? To run against an intel processor, you need at least Mac OS X Leopard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable 64 bit mode in the BIOS of the host PC. This is generally straightforward but some vendors do not support it.

Comment: The F10 setup guide for the DX2420 (see http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01695372/c01695372.pdf) doesn't currently appear to have any way of enabling the Intel VT extensions but it may depend on the rev of the firmware installed.

Comment: You appear to be right there. This may become more obvious over time as support for Windows 7 XP mode also requires hardware virtualization support so systems that can't support it are going to get flagged, hopefully this may also encourage vendors to release firmware updates that support it, AFAIK there is no technical reason not to (provided the CPU is compatible).

Comment: btw win7 xp mode does not require special hardware anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Use VMware version velow 7.0.0 build-203739

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 of the 3 E7500 parts supports VT-d ([Clicky](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=36503)), plus not all HP BIOSs or chipsets support it anyway, there have been no updates to the firmware either - I think you're out of luck sorry.